# Virtual Scrolling - Without Ajax

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I've been looking around the net at various 'infinite scroll' solutions that let a user scroll through data or images on your site and either loop the data back to the start or load bits in as they progress through. For example in a select box like:

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

What I am trying to do is something similar but I already have a complete data set of 200+ records in an array each of which I render out into list items. Only 5 list items fit within the screen at a time so every time I reach the end of that set the next set is already there waiting to be scrolled in (using touch/mouse events).

I've tried appending/prepending elements on as I move into each data set but this is very slow on mobile devices. What I tried next is something like this:

1) Create a number of place holders.

2) When the place holders are scrolled out of the visual boundary, push them back to their         initial position (with new data), creating the illusion of a seamless scroll.

3) Figure out from the box position a page index to grab data from. Re-populate all the place holders with the new data.

Within touch/mouse move event handler:

```
ondrag: function(e) {
  var top, row, rows, delta = 1, prefix;

  if(e.direction === 'up') {
    e.distance = e.distance * -1;
  }

  rows = Math.floor(this._grid.scrollHeight / this._grid.ticketHeight); 

  // Use a simpler row-snap rule.
  top = (this._previous.top + e.distance) * delta;  // Top offset.
  row = Math.floor(top / this.rowHeight);  // Row position.

  // Makes the scroll infinite by seamlessly bouncing back.
  if(Math.abs(row) > rows) {                
     top = (e.distance * delta);        
  }

  elems = this.$el.find('.ticketRow');
  for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.webkitTransform = 'translate(0px,' + ((i * this.rowHeight) + top) + 'px)';       
  }

  if(this._offset !== Math.abs(row)) {
    this._offset = Math.abs(row);

    if(e.direction == 'down') {
      this._track--;
    } else {
      this._track++;
    }
    // Get new data from data source and apply it to the place holders.
    this.update(this._track);
  }
},
```

This however creates a nasty bouncing/jittery effect. I've also tried setting the new positions of each row to multiples of the distance moved but I still get quite erratic results.

My question(s) are, am I approaching this correctly? is there anything out there that does this for me already? Better still, where is the flaw in my math in the above?

Any help appreciated!

Note: I am using [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) to capture my touch-gestures.

Comment: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/
Looks great but I'm not after an excel-style grid.

Comment: +1! Looking for basically the same thing for displaying a list view with lots of results on mobile.

Comment: I've got a solution for this issue. It's basically a simplified/vertical version of this: http://cubiq.org/swipeview

Comment: is very easy. first you want to get the offset.top for your 150th item or so, then get the 150th height. once you have that use an onscroll event, to trigger the loop to append rows 1 through 100 on the bottom of the list etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting all the items to `display: none` and upon initialization showing the first five and then just setting display to `block` using scrollPosition?